# stretching a background image using css / javascript

Tags: javascript, css

This is the code I am using:

```
  $('a.youtube-video').each(function() {
    var videoId = $(this).attr('data-video');
    var videoThumbnail = "http://img.youtube.com/vi/" + videoId + "/0.jpg";
    var videoBackground = $('<span class="youtube-thumbnail"></span>');
    videoBackground.css({
    background:"#fff url('"+videoThumbnail+"') no-repeat"          
    });
```

I am trying to style the background thumbnail so it covers the the span but I have tried everything thing and I cannot get it to work. What am I doing wrong?

I thought this would work but it doesn't

```
background:"#fff url('"+videoThumbnail+"') no-repeat",   
background-size:"cover"
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This issue is that you're trying to set a CSS property using javascript with object syntax, but you're not adapting the style rule to standard javascript object syntax.  Basically, `background-size` should be `backgroundSize` if you're setting it like this:

```
videoBackground.css({
    background: "#fff url('"+videoThumbnail+"') no-repeat",
    backgroundSize: 'cover'
});
```

As a rule, when you are using a javascript object or directly setting the attribute of a style object, you need to change any rules with a dash in the rule name to be camel cased.

**Edit:**  Wrapping in quotes also works:

```
videoBackground.css({
    "background": "#fff url('"+videoThumbnail+"') no-repeat",
    "background-size": 'cover'
});
```

Comment: That's right, I've automatically placed `background-size` in parentheses when tried it with jQuery, which also works :)

Answer (score 0):

Try `background-size:100% 100%;`

---

### Edit:

The above code is in css. When used in jQuery's css function, either use `backgroundSize: 100% 100%` or `"background-size": 100% 100%`.

Comment: Nope still no luck

Comment: What was the result and what is it you want to happen differently?